# Test callback invocation at the end of promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, bluebird, sinon-chai

I am dealing with a code mixing node-style callbacks and Bluebird promises, and I need to write some unit tests for it.

In particular, `cache.js` exposes the `init()` function, which works with promises. It is then called by the `doSomething()` function in another file (e.g. `index.js`) which in turn accepts a callback that has to be invoked at the end of `init()`.

Pseudocode is as follows:

```
// [ cache.js ]
function init() {
  return performInitialisation()
    .then((result) => return result);
}


// [ index.js ]
var cache = require('./cache');

function doSomething(callback) {
  console.log('Enter');

  cache.init()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Invoking callback');
      callback(null);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Invoking callback with error');
      callback(err);
    });

  console.log('Exit');
}
```

A possible unit test could be (showing only relevant code):

```
// [ index.test.js ]
...
var mockCache = sinon.mock(cache);
...
it('calls the callback on success', function(done) {
  mockCache.expects('init')
    .resolves({});

  var callback = sinon.spy();

  doSomething(callback);
  expect(callback).to.have.been.calledOnce;
  done();
});
```

This test passes, however changing the expectation to `not.have.been.calledOnce` also passes, which is wrong.

Also, console logs are out of sequence:

```
Enter
Exit
Invoking callback
```

I have looked at several possibilities, none of which worked:

- Using chai-as-promised, e.g. `expect(callback).to.eventually.have.been.calledOnce;`
- Refactoring `doSomething()` to be simply:

  function doSomething(callback) {
    cache.init()
      .asCallback(callback);
  }

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> console logs are out of sequence

The logs are in the correct order because your `Promise` will be async meaning, at the very least, the internal console logs calls in `then` & `catch` will run on the next tick.

As to why the test is failing is the result of a couple of issues, first one is you don't appear to have `sinon-chai` configured correctly, or at best your `calledOnce` assertion isn't kicking in. Just to confirm, the top of your test file should something like:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");

chai.use(sinonChai);
```

If you have that and it's still not working correctly then might be worth opening an issue on the `sinon-chai` lib, however, a simple workaround is to switch to [sinon assertions](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.4.1/assertions/) e.g.

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(callback)
```

Secondly, when you do eventually fix this, you'll probably find that the test will now fail...everytime. Reason being you've got the same problem in your test that you have with your logging - your asserting before the internal promise has had a chance to resolve. Simplest way of fixing this is actually using your `done` handler from Mocha as your assertion

```
mockCache.expects('init').resolves({});
doSomething(() => done());
```

In other words, if `done` get's called then you know the callback has been called :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If I do `doSomething(() => done());` then I won't be able to test the error condition, right? I mean I won't see if the callback is invoked with the error argument.

Comment: @rippeltippel your handling the callback, so the very fact that `done` gets called and the test passes _is_ your check. If for whatever reason `callback` doesn't get called your test would timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Following [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82586/james)' comment I revisited my tests like this:

```
it('calls the callback on success', function(done) {
  mockCache.expects('init')
    .resolves({});

  doSomething(done);
});

it('calls the callback on error', function(done) {
  mockCache.expects('init')
    .rejects('Error');

  doSomething((err) => {
    if (err === 'Error') {
      done();
    } else {
      done(err);
    }
  });
});
```